# Cloneable interface in j2me

Tags: java-me, cloneable

I want to implement cloneable interface but I am unable to. I am using J2me, it gives me error
create interface Cloneable in your package. As far as I know J2me allows to implement Cloneable interface as it is a part of jdk1 1.0. Kindly help me

Comment: why do you want Cloneable? how do you expect to use it? Also, it's not welcome here to use answers to expand your question. Instead, edit your post to add more or in this case, you could also ask the question in comments to [Ray's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238517/cloneable-interface-in-j2me/7238552#7238552)

Comment: @gnat I want to use cloneable because I want that when a user clicks duplicate then a copy of a particular class object should be created...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see Cloneable [here](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) or [here](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/index.html).  Which JavaME API are you using?

Comment: Ok thanx!! I was looking at some other API.. Well do you know any alternative which I can use instead of cloneable.

Comment: as almost a wild guess JavaME CDC 1.1.2 JSR 218 has [Cloneable](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/java/lang/Cloneable.html) - though question doesn't give any indication of whether it's about this or other JSR